# Write on page load javascript function from code behind c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamic, code-behind

i have this function on my aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad() {
    //code here
}
</script>
```

and i need to override this function dymanically from my .cs

i have tried to use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` but that only creates a new javascript function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using the RegisterStartupScript: `pageLoad = function () { // your new stuff here }`

Comment: Most basic way would be to nest this function (or its body) in a `PlaceHolder` runat="server", and overwrite the content of the placeholder in code behind

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty div on your ASPX page with `runat="server"`, and then setting the `InnerHtml` to the JavaScript code.  This offers a lot of flexibility and will allow you to apply whatever logic you need depending on your situation.

```
.aspx

<div id="script" runat="server">
</div>


.cs

script.InnerHtml = "<script type='text/javascript'>//your javascript here</script>";
```